# Doctrine2 many-to-many relationship with multiple tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I am using Symfony2 and Doctrine2 to build an application. One part of the application deals with addresses. I have one table "address" and three tables that connect to it with a many-to-many relationship (employee, client, supplier). I set this up with one connecting table "contact_address".

How do I create my entities with the many to many relationship? In my employee, client and supplier entities I have

```
/**
 * @var Addressess
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="contacts")
 */
private $addresses;
```

what do I put in my address entity?

```
    /**
     * @var Contacts
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Employee", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="contact_address",
     *   joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="addressID", referencedColumnName="addressID")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employeeID", referencedColumnName="employeeID")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $contacts;
```

was my first thought, but what abot the clients and suppliers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can an address be linked to several persons at a time? That seems a bit weird to me...

In any case, I would advise you to have one entity Contact, on a One-to-Many relationship with Address, and either a one-to-one between Contact and Employee, Contact and Client, and Contact and Supplier, or have Employee, Client and Supplier inherit from Contact.

Comment: Well I'm thinking about the case where for example several clients work for the same company and have the same address. So you would have a table clients with all common fields then an extra table for employees, clients and suppliers with just the fields specific for each entity?

Comment: Well that's the solution I picked for a project myself. It's quite a convenient way to deal with the problem of addresses. Although, even in your case, I'd recommend to link an address only to one Contact (or whatever you call it). There might be duplicates, but just think about the case the employee changes address but not the company he's working for... You'd have to change the address for everyone, or create a new address for him... It is simpler (and, I think, better) to have only one entity linked with several addresses.

Comment: OK I changed the schema to a One-to-Many unidirecational relationship, with an address belonging to only one contact, and a contact being able to have more than one address. This [blogpost](http://www.benedikt-wolters.de/blog/web-development/20/doctrine2-one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table-association-mapping) helped me set that up in doctrine. A good supplement to the doctrine documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Don't hesitate to come on the symfony2 chat if you have further questions, or on the IRC.